# Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

What are the differences between Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Report sold by SAP?

Since Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010 is free and come with Visual Studio 2010, is there any limitation such as number of report can be built per site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version that comes with Visual Studio is FREE and you can make as much reports as you can and deploy the runtime engine with your application at no extra charge. [check this website](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-visualstudio/licensing/index.epx) for the full details.

Regarding the full SAP crystal reports, Basically the Visual Studio version is a mini version of the Crystal Reports which has much more features. here is a comparison between the full and the visual studio versions (for 2008 version) which is similar to the 2010 version:

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-visualstudio/comparison/index.epx

Comment: I had a question a few weeks ago about how the full versions of Crystal were supposed to line up with the .Net releases.  I called the SAP support before purchasing new licenses and this is basically what they told me (they also confirmed what you posted here, that the VS Crystal Editor is just a stripped down version):  http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=470

Answer (score 1):

Crystal report has a limit to display number of reports once it is hosted in IIS. This will throw as ‘Maximum report processing jobs limit”. To avoid this dispose and close the report in its unload event.

```
Protected void report_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       rptDocument.Dispose();
       rptDocument.Close();
}
```